# Attribute 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' attribute for a package

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have **package A** and **package B** with mapped entities. I want **package A** to be updated automatically so I set value 'update' for 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto'. At the same time I do not want the mapping from **package B** to be applied to the tables in the database automatically when I run the app. I want to update them either manually or using version control. The problem is that I am talking about different **packages, not modules**. So there cannot be different settings files. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working out-of-the-box would be if the entities in both packages were being managed by two different `SessionFactory` / `EntityManagerFactory` instances.

If you want all entities managed by a single instance, then you cannot do this out-of-the-box directly.

One option that does come to mind is using the *Hibernate Tools* schema export ant task.  The idea here is that you shift the generation of the schema changes offline at build time to a file.  You can then rename this file to `import.sql` and place it in the root of your application's classpath and Hibernate will automatically execute those statements at startup.

I'm not sure if the *Hibernate Tools* ant task allows you to filter the objects of interest but perhaps if it does not you can either supply a second configuration restricting its scope to only the entities in the package you want automatically managed or use a follow-up task to filter the generated sql file.